# Notepad++ regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

First of all, regular expressions are quite possibly the most confusing thing I have every dealt with - with that being said I cannot believe how efficient they can make ones life.

So I am trying to understand the wildcard regex with no luck

**Need to turn**

```
f_firstname
f_lastname
f_dob       
f_origincountry 
f_landing
```

**Into**

```
':f_firstname'=>$f_firstname,
':f_lastname'=>$f_lastname,
':f_dob'=>$f_dob,
':f_origincountry'=>$f_origincountry,   
':f_landing'=>$f_landing,
```

In the answer can you please briefly describe the regex you are using, I have been reading the tutorials but they boggle my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: As Chris points out, you can improve the regex by cleaning up any white space there may be in the target string. I also replace the dot with `\w` as he did because it's better practice than using the `.`

```
Search: ^f_(\w+)\s*$
^     # start at the beginning of the line
f_    # look for f_
(\w+) # capture in a group all characters
\s*   # optionally skip over (don't capture) optional whitespace
$     # end of the line

Replace: ':f_\1'=>$f_\1,
':f_    # beginning of replacement string
\1      # the group of characters captured above
'=>$f_  # some more characters for the replace
\1,     # the capture group (again)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Your explanation makes so much more sense then all the tutorials I have read. I can now use this as a reference card :) Will accept in 3 mins.

Comment: There's a problem with this search phrase in that if the end of line has spaces your replace will not look right. eg `f_dob    ` <-- note the 3 trailing spaces gives `':f_dob   '=>$f_dob   ,`

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice the spaces before posting. I'll make a correction.

Comment: See my answer for something that will work - but in your case and for @mcflause to aware of the dot (.+) isn't recommended as a solution since this matches on spaces etc basically anything but line-break

Answer (score 2):

```
Find: (^.*)

Replace with: ':$1'=>$$1,
```

Answer (score 1):

Find What:

```
(f_\w+)
```

Here we're matching `f_` followed by a word character `\w+` (the plus mean one or more times). Wrapping the whole thing in brackets means we can reference this group in the replace pattern

Replace With:

```
':\1'=>$\1,
```

This is simply your result phrase but instead of hardcoding the f words I've put `\1` to reference the group in the search